# Crypttab doesn't respect keyfile-timeout

Tags: linux, usb, luks

I want to use a partition on a USB device as keypartiton for my luks encrypted home but I also want it to fallback to asking a passphrase if the USB is not plugged in. I have added a passphrase and the USB as keys to luks and I can open them manually with both. How can I make it so that it asks for passphrase when USB is not found.

/etc/crypttab:

```
home    UUID="cea24d85-1654-477f-9fda-a050289ec56e" /dev/disk/by-partuuid/e763deac-79f7-9c41-9a18-81b0976b73a7  keyfile-timeout=1s
```

The `dev/disk/by-partuuid/e763deac-79f7-9c41-9a18-81b0976b73a7` is the keypartiton.

Comment: Do you use systemd? That seems a bug/missing feature https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/21993